# Can't import Python module because Difference in "sys.path" and "sys.executable"

Tags: python, import, module, jupyter-notebook, sys

I'm install "Jupyter notebook" and also have "Jupyter notebook in Visual Studio Code"
When I run "pip3 install some_module" then it can import in "Jupyter notebook in Visual Studio Code" BUT CAN'T in "Jupyter notebook"
I relize that in "Jupyter notebook in Visual Studio Code"
sys.executable = /usr/bin/python3
But in "Jupyter notebook"
sys.executable = /home/binh/.local/my_project_env/bin/python3

Answer (score 0):

When working with ***Jupyter notebooks***, it makes sense having Python virtual environments containing just the modules that you need. This provides a guarantee that the notebook running on the particular versions of Python modules you have installed, will always run correctly if those modules in those versions are present.

From the *sys.executable* paths you provided, it seems like you have multiple versions of Python installed. When you run *"pip3 install <some_module>"*, you are only installing that module to the *system-wide Python installation*, unless you are within a Python virtual environment. With that said, there are 2 possible solutions to your problem:

1. The most recommended would be to create a virtual environment as explained in detail [here](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/).
2. Alternatively, you could also set the Jupyter Notebook's sys.executable path to point to the *system-wide Python installation* by simply changing the path to your local */usr/bin/python3*. However, this is not recommended.